# Invertible matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

[image]

I've spent 30 mins plugging in examples into each one and still came up with the wrong answer. I got that A,B,D and F were correct.

Comment: For matrices, $AB$ need not be the same as $BA$.

Comment: What are the entries of the matices?

Comment: @quid I just used an arbitrary A and B that were Invertible

Comment: That's not what I meant. Are the entries real numbers or can they be something else?

Comment: @quid My image is the whole question, this is basic linear algebra so I'm assuming they can only be real numbers

Comment: Why do you think C is false? Multiply it out and simplify. Don't use sample matrices unless you have to show a counter example. Instead, exploit the properties given to you, plus the general results from earlier lessons. Mathematics is cumulative: you have to be able to use it all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment it is not always true that $AB = BA$ (likely you have seen an example), thus A and F are false.

B is true if and only if $2$ has a multiplicative inverse (which likely is to be assumed in your case, but were false for  example if you'd limit yourself to integer matrices).

There is no good reason for D to be true, you should be able to cook up a counter example. (Look among 2 by 2 matrices with $0$ on the diagonal.)

E is false, and it would be easy to find a counterexample (it is not even true for 1 by 1 matrices!).

But C is true. Just expand it and simplify.